# php: remove brackets/contents from a string?

Tags: php, regex

If I have a string like this:

```
$str = "blah blah blah (a) (b) blah blah blah";
```

How can I regex so that the output is:

```
$str = "blah blah blah blah blah blah";
```

It needs to be able to support any number of bracket pairs inside a string.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$str = trim(preg_replace('/\s*\([^)]*\)/', '', $str));
```

Note, this answer removes whitespace around the bracket too, unlike the other suggestions.

The trim is in case the string starts with a bracketed section, in which case the whitespace following it isn't removed.

Comment: Note that this will break for "(())" or any unbalanced parentheses, but that may not be a problem.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/\([^)]*\)|[()]/', '', $str)
```

Comment: The educational explanation is missing from this answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = preg_replace('~\(.*?\)~', '', $string);
```

Comment: The educational explanation is missing from this answer.