# PHP function to delete all between certain character(s) in string

Tags: php, string

I'm interested in `function delete_all_between($char1, $char2, $string)`
that will search given $string for $char1 and $char2 and, if such has been found, clear $string from substring between these two characters, **including** $char1 and $char2 itself.

Example:

```
$string = 'Some valid and <script>some invalid</script> text!';
delete_all_between('<script>', '</script>', $string);
```

Now, $string should contain just

```
'Some valid and  text'; //note two spaces between 'and  text'
```

Does someone have quick solution?

Comment: What's the ultimate purpose here? To filter HTML out?

Comment: You don't want to do this to filter out HTML content. Use [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) instead.

Comment: @pp19dd, to delete all content between certain tags.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1336672/984422

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
<?php

$string = 'Some valid and <script>some invalid</script> text!';
$out = delete_all_between('<script>', '</script>', $string);
print($out);

function delete_all_between($beginning, $end, $string) {
  $beginningPos = strpos($string, $beginning);
  $endPos = strpos($string, $end);
  if ($beginningPos === false || $endPos === false) {
    return $string;
  }

  $textToDelete = substr($string, $beginningPos, ($endPos + strlen($end)) - $beginningPos);

  return delete_all_between($beginning, $end, str_replace($textToDelete, '', $string)); // recursion to ensure all occurrences are replaced
}
```

Comment: But when there are more than one <script></script> in a sentence, it will only delete the first one, not all...?

Comment: very good, you should change to  $endPos = strpos($string, $end, $beginningPos); to geht the right $end

Comment: @Tom you are absolutely right. I faced the same problem, and solved it like this: I put the the line
$out = delete_all_between('<script>', '</script>', $string);
in a while loop, that checks, if there is still a script-tag after deleting one and than redo the action till all script-tags are gone:
while (strpos($string, '<script>') !== false) {
 $out = delete_all_between('<script>', '</script>', $string);
}

Comment: This makes it WAY too hard. Just use the one liner below and vote it up!

Comment: Using regex on large complex strings is far slower than standard string replacements. It is recommended to use standard string replacement over regex for better performance.

Comment: sorry, but this not work with myltibyte strings, other languages, non English letters !

Comment: NOTE, this method will not work if the html has attributes included in the <script> tags (e.g. <script type='javascript'...>). It will also fail if the case of the tags is not as expected.

Answer (score 61):

Here's a oneliner:

`preg_replace('/START[\s\S]+?END/', '', $string);`

Replace `START` and `END` :) Credits go to another SO thread!

Comment: This is super elegant and simple

Comment: Vote for a non function solution.

Comment: How do you not include the characters themselves?

Comment: the best option :)

Comment: wrote my own function with strpos/substr that kinda worked (it started busting through all reasonable php memory limits), but then I found this gold nugget :)

Comment: to save future readers puzzling why this gives an error if applied to the original question: if START or END contain / then it needs to be escaped with \. Or one can use | instead of / for the separator.

Answer (score 1):

I think `substr()` works too slow. The best way is:

```
return substr($string, 0, $beginningPos) . 
       substr($string, $endPos + strlen($end));
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I was looking for a function, which gives me simple and stable solution to grab out all the variables of TWIG template.
The proposed regexps did not work well for many reasons so I decided to go by just erasing all the content between tags instead of counting tags ^_^.

```
/**
     * deletes ALL the string contents between all the designated characters
     * @param $start - pattern start 
     * @param $end   - pattern end
     * @param $string - input string, 
     * @return mixed - string
     */
    function auxDeleteAllBetween($start, $end, $string) {
        // it helps to assembte comma dilimited strings
        $string = strtr($start. $string . $end, array($start => ','.$start, $end => chr(2)));
        $startPos  = 0;
        $endPos = strlen($string);
        while( $startPos !== false && $endPos !== false){
            $startPos = strpos($string, $start);
            $endPos = strpos($string, $end);
            if ($startPos === false || $endPos === false) {
                $run = false;
                return $string;
            }
            $textToDelete = substr($string, $startPos, ($endPos + strlen($end)) - $startPos);
            $string = str_replace($textToDelete, '', $string);
        }
        return $string;
    }

    /**
     * This function is intended to replace
     * //preg_match_all('/\{\%\s*([^\%\}]*)\s*\%\}|\{\{\s*([^\}\}]*)\s*\}\}/i', $this->_tplSubj, $matchesSubj);
     * which did not give intended results for some reason.
     *
     * @param $inputTpl
     * @return array
     */
    private function auxGetAllTags($inputTpl){
        $inputTpl = strtr($inputTpl, array('}}' => ','.chr(1), '{{' => chr(2)));
        return explode(',',$this->auxDeleteAllBetween(chr(1),chr(2),$inputTpl));
    }


$template = '<style>
td{border-bottom:1px solid #eee;}</style>
<p>Dear {{jedi}},<br>New {{padawan}} is waiting for your approval: </p>
<table border="0">
<tbody><tr><td><strong>Register as</strong></td><td>{{register_as}}, user-{{level}}</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Name</strong></td><td>{{first_name}} {{last_name}}</td></tr>...';

print_r($this->auxGetAllTags($template));
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the [first](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13031540/revisions) version has problems, this is my corrected version (if the $end string appear also before $beginning string)

```
<?php 
$string = 'Some </script> valid and <script>some invalid</script> text!';
$out = delete_all_between('<script>', '</script>', $string);
print($out);

function delete_all_between($beginning, $end, $string) {
    $beginningPos = strpos($string, $beginning);
    $tmpstring = substr($string, $beginningPos);  
    $endPos = strpos($tmpstring, $end);
    if ($beginningPos === false || $endPos === false) {
        return $string;
    }
    $textToDelete = substr($string, $beginningPos, ($endPos + strlen($end)) );
    return delete_all_between($beginning, $end, str_replace($textToDelete, '', $string)); // recursion to ensure all occurrences are replaced
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. The question shows exactly one "signature" for/of `delete_all_between('<script>', '</script>', $string);`, your answer *one* implementation. Considering the order in which answers are presented *does* change (and user names might): What exactly are you referring to when claiming `the first version has problems`? *What* problems, and how to reproduce?

Comment: yes, your're right sorry, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13031540/revisions) this version, as described in the post comments, if there are many $end string as the example:
`$string = 'Some </script> valid and <script>some invalid</script> text!';`

Answer (score 0):

I want to delete the  tag in php since I want to remove the unused tag before parsing html into DOMDocument.

Here is the code I used.
Cursor is 0 at the beginning case. It's just used for recursive in the program.

```
function delete_all_betweenV2($cursor, $beginning, $end, $string, $retainSelf) {
    echo '>>>> Start '.'<br>';
    $beginningPos = strpos($string, $beginning, $cursor);
    $endPos = strpos($string, $end, $beginningPos);
    
    if ($beginningPos === false || $endPos === false) {
      echo '>>>> End '.'<br>';
      return $string;
    }    
    
    if($endPos >= strlen($string)) {
      echo '>>>> End '.'<br>';
      return $string;
    }
    
    $lenOfBeginning = strlen($beginning);
    $lenOfEnd = strlen($end);
    
    $result = $string;
    if($retainSelf) {
      echo 'b4 input String: '.$string.'<br>';
      echo 'b4 cursor = : '.$cursor. '<br>';
      echo 'b4 string: '.$string. '<br>';
      echo 'b4 beginning Pos: '.$beginningPos.'<br>';
      echo 'b4 end Pos: '.$endPos.'<br>';
      echo 'b4 length to be cut is: '.(($endPos - $lenOfEnd) - $beginningPos).'<br>';
      
      if($cursor > 0) {
        echo 'cursor is greater than 0'.'<br>';
        $textToDelete = substr($string, $beginningPos + $lenOfBeginning, ($endPos - $lenOfEnd) - $beginningPos);
      } else {
        echo 'cursor is NOT greater than 0'.'<br>';
        $textToDelete = substr($string, $beginningPos + $lenOfBeginning, ($endPos - $lenOfEnd) - $beginningPos);
      }
      
      echo 'TextToDelete:'.$textToDelete.'<br>';
        
      //$stringStart = substr($string, 0, $beginningPos + $lenOfBeginning);
      //echo $stringStart.'<br>';
      //$stringTail = substr($string, $endPos, strlen($string));
      //echo $stringTail.'<br>';    
      $result = str_replace($textToDelete, '', $string);
      $cursor = $beginningPos + $lenOfBeginning; // just make sure that the cursor search next character/word
      echo 'After cursor = : '.$cursor. '<br>';
      echo 'After result: '.$result. '<br>';
      echo 'After len of result: '.strlen($result). '<br>';
    } else {
        //$stringStart = substr($string, 0, $beginningPos);
        //echo $stringStart.'<br>';
        //$stringTail = substr($string, $endPos + $lenOfEnd, strlen($string));
        //echo $stringTail.'<br>';
        $cursor = 0;
        
        $textToDelete = substr($string, $beginningPos, ($endPos + $lenOfEnd) - $beginningPos);
        echo 'TextToDelete:'.$textToDelete.'<br>';
        $result = str_replace($textToDelete, '', $string);
    } 
    echo '>>>> End '.'<br>';
    return delete_all_betweenV2($cursor, $beginning, $end, $result, $retainSelf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as a revision to AndreaTS's delete_all_between(), but to handle tag attributes (e.g. `<script type='abc'>`) and to handle case insensitivity, I've got this...

```
    function delete_all_between(string $html, string $tag) {
        $startTag="<$tag ";
        $endTag="</$tag>";
        $html     =str_ireplace("<$tag>", "<$tag >", $html);
        $startPos = stripos($html, $startTag);
        $tmpStr = substr($html, $startPos);
        $endPos = stripos($tmpStr, $endTag);
        if ($startPos === false || $endPos === false) {
            return $html;
        }
        $textToDelete = substr($html, $startPos, ($endPos + strlen($startTag))+1 );
        return delete_all_between(str_replace($textToDelete, '', $html), $tag); // recursion to ensure all occurrences are replaced
    }
```

See http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1b984b61cfd1c9cea4c6eef1d765ff387a4cd9e9 for a php sandbox running this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a string that consists of multiple occurance of tags like <start>xyz<end> in a string. I was able to remove using the code below:

`{{preg_replace('/(\<start>.+?)+(\<end>)/i', "", $string)}}`

Note : If you  or  is kind of a special character like $, @ etc escape it using backslash like \<start> or <end> respectively. So the end result would be like :

`{{preg_replace('/(\\\<start>.+?)+(\\\<end>)/i', "", $string)}}`

To be precise :

`{{preg_replace('/(\\$.+?)+(\\@)/i', "", $string)}}`

Answer (score -2):

You can use double str_replace()
`$q = str_replace('<script>', '', $string);
$p = str_replace('some invalid', '', $q);
echo $p;`