# How to trim the string from a character to the next immediate occurring of another character

Tags: php, string

```
http://zyx.com/abc.html?style=1876&price=2%2C1000&size=68
http://zyx.com/abc.html?price=2%2C1000&style=1876&size=68
```

The url can appear in any of the two form:

I want to remove the entire `price=2%2C1000&` from my url.
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031250/php-function-to-delete-all-between-certain-characters-in-string) thread. But with no luck

How to do this?

Comment: Did you try `str_replace('price=2%2C1000','',$url);` ?

Comment: Its not always the `price=2%2C1000&` it can be different and multiple values for price. eg `price=1%2C1000%2C2%2C1000&`

Comment: How many variables will be after price variable ?

Comment: @MahmoodRehman: there can 1 or 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
 $str = explode("price","http://zyx.com/abc.html?style=1876&price=1%2C1000%2C2%2C1000&size=68");
$removeable_str = explode("&", $str[1]);
unset($removeable_str[0]);
echo $str[0].join("&",$removeable_str);
```

Comment: Its not always the `price=2%2C1000&` it can be different and multiple values for price. eg `price=1%2C1000%2C2%2C1000&`

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
var s = "http://zyx.com/abc.html?style=1876&price=2%2C1000&size=68"
s.split("price=")[1].split("&")[0];
```