# remove all content inside script tags

Tags: php

I have a string like

```
$result = '
  stuff
  stuff
  <script>
    stuff I want to remove
  </script>
  morestuff
  morestuff
';
```

I want to remove everything between the script tags and the script tags themselves

I have so far

```
$result = preg_replace("/<script>.+?<\/script>/i", "", $result)
```

however it is not working

Comment: Use a mature HTML purifier.  Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Can't you google that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7131156/2611927

Comment: I did, but I didn't find that...ty

Comment: PHP - You can control of the content - so why is the script stuff there in the first place?

Comment: What's wrong with [`strip_tags`](http://us3.php.net/strip_tags) or [`fgetss`](http://us3.php.net/fgetss)?  Anyway, `.+?` isn't doing what I think you mean it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$string = 'Some valid and <script>some invalid</script> text!';
$out = delete_all_between('<script>', '</script>', $string);
print($out);

function delete_all_between($beginning, $end, $string) {
  $beginningPos = strpos($string, $beginning);
  $endPos = strpos($string, $end);
  if (!$beginningPos || !$endPos) {
    return $string;
  }

  $textToDelete = substr($string, $beginningPos, ($endPos + strlen($end)) - $beginningPos);

  return str_replace($textToDelete, '', $string);
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031250/php-function-to-delete-all-between-certain-characters-in-string) by [Tim S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995476/tim-s)