# Removing lines that begin with © (copyright) symbol using PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Background: We are merging the pages of some documents so they look like one nice long page rather than split into hundreds. To do this, we need to remove the page numbers, HR tags, copyright notices from the bottom of each page, then manually adding the copyright notice to the final page. We have found a simple pattern to identify a footer, and have outlined it below.

To clean up the footer, I'm trying to remove all text between the br and copyright symbol and the closing a tag

```
In the beginning the universe was created.
<br/>© 2010 Some message here<br/>
<hr/>
<a name=3></a>
This has made a lot of people very angry and been widely regarded as a bad move.
```

Expected results:

```
In the beginning the universe was created.
This has made a lot of people very angry and been widely regarded as a bad move.
```

The most promising code I have found is this here: [PHP function to delete all between certain character(s) in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031250/php-function-to-delete-all-between-certain-characters-in-string)

But when I try to put it into use I am not getting a match.

```
    $contents = delete_all_between('<br/>©', '</a>', $contents);
    $contents = delete_all_between('<br/>&#169;', '</a>', $contents);
```

I have tried using the © symbol as well as & # 169; and a few other variations, but I'm out of ideas.

I suspect it's something simple, hoping someone here can put me out of my misery.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: It works for me: http://ideone.com/0nVZoO

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why the downvotes? If I could have asked better, I'd appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Noted. Thanks @halfer. I'm still learning to ride here without the training wheels.  :)

Comment: No worries. You can always have a read of [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/), which will give you a lot of information about the assumptions, guidelines and memes that make the site tick.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is clearly an illicit request of violating copyrights principally.

Comment: Some more background for you @holex. Clearly you like to jump to conclusions.

Comment: it is always highly suspicious when someone needs to write a custom(!) server-side(!) parser for removing(!) copyright(!) information of an already(!) rendered(!) output(!) in runtime(!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be completed with a regex in PHP. Here is an example:

```
$text = "All of your stuff. @This will be deleted";
echo preg_replace("/(@.+)(<)/", "", $text);
```

Simply, that code above will replace all code that starts with `@` and a closing tag.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Hi Michael, this is very close, but it is stopping at the first closing tag (which in my case is a <br/>. I need it to stop when it finds a closing </a> tag.

Comment: This answers the question by simply removing all text in-between the `@` symbol and a closing HTML tag.

Comment: @WonkotheSane, do you want it to stop at **ONLY** `</a>` tags?

Comment: Yes, should stop only at </a> tags.

Comment: @WonkotheSane, Replace the old `preg_replace()` with this one, `preg_replace("/(@.+)(?=(<\/a>))/", "", $text);`

Comment: Wonderful! I added isU so it spans multiple lines and is un-greedy and it works perfectly. Thanks for the prompt help Michael!

Answer (score 1):

Check the encoding of the document your working with. A more common way to create a copyright symbol would be `&copy;`
 [Copyright encodings](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a9/index.htm)