# How remove part of big html string with starting and ending part?

Tags: php, strpos

i have a big string that holds a big html string. Now i want to remove part of html from the big string $code. The part that i want to remove has starting point:

```
<div id="crumbsPanel">
```

and end point :`<div id="ThumbnailsPanel">`

so my big string $code has to exclude anything between those start and end point! could any one tell me how this can be done?

Comment: Did you read about [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)? It might help you!

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031250/php-function-to-delete-all-between-certain-characters-in-string