# Remove <select> from html with PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace, html-parsing

I need to remove entire select drop downs with all their options from HTML using PHP.

i assume preg replace would do it, but i don't know how to use it like that.

All the html is in a variable.

```
$html = "

<p> something </p>

<select name='bla' id='bla' class='REMOVE'>
<option></option>
<option></option>
<option></option>
<option></option>
</select>

<p> something </p>

<p> something </p>

";
```

Converted to....

```
$html = "

<p> something </p>

<p> something </p>

<p> something </p>

";
```

Comment: Don't use `preg_replace`. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272726/how-to-delete-element-with-domdocument and/or the larger topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php.

Comment: please give your desired output here ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP function to delete all between certain character(s) in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031250/php-function-to-delete-all-between-certain-characters-in-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simply use a combination of `explode()`,  `substr()` and `implode()` with a simple Loop to achieve that (*if you prefer not to use Regex - that is...*). The Snippet below (which you may [Quick-Test Here](https://eval.in/671636)) demonstrates how:

```
<?php

    $html = "

                <p> something </p>

                <select name='bla' id='bla' class='REMOVE'>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                </select>

                <p> something </p>

                <p> something </p>

                ";

        $arrParts   = explode("</select>", $html);
        foreach($arrParts as &$part){
            if($selPos = strpos($part, "<select")){
                $part = substr($part, 0, $selPos);
            }
        }
        $html = implode("", $arrParts);
        var_dump($html);
```