# PHP function Delete characters in string Between Tokens Unless Tokens Match a specific String

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

Ok so here is what I am trying to do, I need a php function that I can pass 4 parameters.

1) A String (Containing Tokens with text between them)

2) A Start Token String Parameter

3) A Stop Token String Parameter

4) A DO NOT DELETE String Parameter

I want to pass a (1)long string to the function and have it remove all the multiple instances of the (2)Start Tokens and all the Text Until The (3)Stop Token, UNLESS the (4)Do NOT DELETE Parameter is present in that part of the String.

The Setup would be like this:

HERE is the way the function would be setup:

```
function CleanUpMyString($string-1, $start-2, $end-3, $keep-4){
// Working Code That Does The Work Here
}
```

The String That I could Pass To The Function May Look Like this examples:

```
$stringTEST = "This is the intro of the string, <<<This Part Would Be Deleted>>> in the next snippet of the string, <<<we will delete another part>>> This is going pretty well. <<<keep>We do not delete this part because of the added token part 'keep>'.>>> We will add some more rambling text here. Then we will add another snippet. <<<We will also delete this one.>>><<<keep>But in the end it is all good!>>>";
```

Assuming I called the function like this:

```
echo CleanUpMyString($stringTEST, '<<<', '>>>', 'keep>');
```

I would get the following output:

```
This is the intro of the string, in the next snippet of the string, This is going pretty well. We do not delete this part because of the added token part 'keep>'. We will add some more rambling text here. Then we will add another snippet. But in the end it is all good!
```

I have no control over the input string, so the tokens could occur anywhere in any number, and there is not rational order in which they may appear.

I really am not sure where to start. I took a look at this thread:

[PHP function to delete all between certain character(s) in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031250/php-function-to-delete-all-between-certain-characters-in-string)

which I thought has been the closest thing to what I wanted, but I could not see how to extend the idea to my application. Any help would be seriously appreciated!

Comment: It looks like the last sentence in the expected output should include `keep>`. Right? Please check [this approach](https://regex101.com/r/DQE8yz/1) - are the results as expected? It can be improved, I just want to clear out the expected behavior.

Comment: @BobC Hope my post will help you out..

Comment: Hey @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the help. No the string part 'keep>' should not be included/kept unless it is NOT preceded by the $start-2 variable. So in this case where I have " We do not delete this part because of the added token part 'keep>' ". it SHOULD be included but every where else it only serves to indicate what part of the string should stay and thus should be deleted. So where I have the part " <<<keep>But in the end it is all good!>>> " We would delete it there. Thanks so much

Comment: Ok, so, like [`(?s)<<<(?:(?!<<<|keep>).)*?>>>|<<<(?:keep>)?(.*?)>>>`](https://regex101.com/r/DQE8yz/2) then? See the [**PHP demo**](http://ideone.com/XLksK6).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you out, Here i am using `preg_match` to gather all matching tokens from `start` to `end` and then we are iterating over `matches` to keep required portion of string and removing `un-necessary part`.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/784473)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$stringTEST = "This is the intro of the string, <<<This Part Would Be Deleted>>> in the next snippet of the string, <<<we will delete another part>>> This is going pretty well. <<<keep>We do not delete this part because of the added token part 'keep>'.>>> We will add some more rambling text here. Then we will add another snippet. <<<We will also delete this one.>>><<<keep>But in the end it is all good!>>>";
echo CleanUpMyString($stringTEST, "<<<", ">>>", "keep>");

function CleanUpMyString($stringTEST, $start, $end, $keep)
{
    $startQuotes=  preg_quote($start);
    $endQuotes=  preg_quote($end);
    preg_match_all("/$startQuotes.*?(?:$endQuotes)/", $stringTEST,$matches);
    foreach($matches[0] as $key => $value)
    {
        if(stristr($value, $start.$keep)!==false)
        {
            $stringTEST= substr_replace($stringTEST,"",strpos($stringTEST, $start.$keep),  strlen($start.$keep));;
            $stringTEST= substr_replace($stringTEST,"",strpos($stringTEST, $end),  strlen($end));
        }
        else
        {
            $stringTEST=  str_replace($value, "", $stringTEST);
        }
    }
    return $stringTEST;
}
```

Comment: You should escape `$start` and `$end` with `preg_quote()`.

Comment: Hey @SahilGulati Thank you so much for the help. Looking at your code and playing with it allowed me to understand the process of what needed to happen. That being said there seems to be some issues with this method. some of the text that should be kept, is not. Also the part 'keep>' should not be a part of the final string UNLESS it is NOT preceded by the $start variable. Also when I run this as a function in my script against a string from the database which contains line breaks it seems to break the execution. I am trying to work it out now to get this working fully. Any more  suggestions?

Comment: @BobC Somehow i misunderstood your post, I am updating my post which your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to use `preg_replace_callback`

```
<?php

function CleanUpMyString($string, $start, $end, $keep)
{
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '~' . preg_quote($start, '~') . '.+?' . preg_quote($end, '~') . '~',
        function ($M) use ($start, $end, $keep) {
            if (strpos($M[0], $keep)) {
                return str_replace([$start, $end, $keep], '', $M[0]);
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        },
        $string
    );
}

$stringTEST = "This is the intro of the string, <<<This Part Would Be Deleted>>> in the next snippet of the string, <<<we will delete another part>>> This is going pretty well. <<<keep>We do not delete this part because of the added token part 'keep>'.>>> We will add some more rambling text here. Then we will add another snippet. <<<We will also delete this one.>>><<<keep>But in the end it is all good!>>>";

echo CleanUpMyString($stringTEST, '<<<', '>>>', 'keep>');
```