# Regex for find and replace to remove string in assert('') statements

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I am updating a legacy application that is riddled with assert('') statements and I am looking to do a find and replace of all occurrences as php 7 depricated assert string statements.  Below are some examples of what I have and the results I would expect afterwords.

```
Currently
assert( '$result === true' );
assert( 'isString( $fileName )' );
After
assert( $result === true );
assert( isString( $fileName ) );
```

Some of them have comments inside them as well which I would like to remove.

```
Currently
assert( '$result === true  /* the only way this could fail is if the user is not logged in, which should not be possible */' );
After
assert( $result === true );
```

Comment: this might help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031250/php-function-to-delete-all-between-certain-characters-in-string

Comment: Those seems to be using preg_replace.  I am looking to do this in vscode and not as a function I am calling within my code.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you all the `asserts` that follow the pattern above but it's very simplistic.

`^(assert\()'([^']|'')*'`

You could use it for a more brute force approach or you could get more fancy with these and have a series `find/replace`'s. It might be hard to find a single expression to cover all cases. If you can't figure it out you may try posting more examples like the one you posted that give a broader look at the transforms you need to make.

Also, I'm no regex expert. I used [this site](https://regex101.com/) to develop that pattern with their helpful hints and a bit of trial and error.

Comment: Thanks Rip.  This gets me to match them all.  Now I just have to come up with the replace statement.