# How to replace string that contain bracket? (Regex)

Tags: php, regex

i want to ask you something simple.
I have string like:

> happy (adj)
>
> sad (v)

and i want to replace those brackets with empty string (" ") so it would be like this:

> happy
>
> sad

i know that i have to use regex but because im new in regex, can u  help me with the pattern guys? thank you :')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php: remove brackets/contents from a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336672/php-remove-brackets-contents-from-a-string) or [Remove Text Between Parentheses PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174362/remove-text-between-parentheses-php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(` and `)` will need to be escaped. `.` is any character and `*` is zero or more occurrences of the previous character/grop; `+`is one or more. So put that together with [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) and you have:

```
<?php
echo preg_replace('/\(.*?\)/', '', 'happy (adj)

sad (v)');
```

Note the `?` as well that takes away the greediness of the `*` quantifier, http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html.

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/zQ5bW1/2
PHP Demo: https://eval.in/595919

or you could use a negated character class to find the closing `)`.

```
echo preg_replace('/\([^)]+\)/', '', 'happy (adj)

sad (v)');
```

Alternative regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/zQ5bW1/3

Comment: I think the space before the bracket should be removed also.

Comment: Not sure if that is OPs intention or not. Here are approaches though if it is, https://regex101.com/r/zQ5bW1/4 or https://regex101.com/r/zQ5bW1/5