# Extract data from string (with default template)

Tags: php, regex

I am having a bit of trouble with PHP, since I basically do not know where to start.

My problem is the following:

I've got CSGO skin names such as:

```
★ StatTrak™ Bayonet | Fade (Minimal Wear)
P250 | Modern Hunter (Field-Tested)
Souvenir AUG | Contractor (Factory New)
StatTrak™ Galil AR | Orange DDPAT (Factory New)
```

Now, I need something which basically figures out the following:

```
Does it contain the star (★)? If so, it's a knife.
Is it StatTrak™?
Is it Souvenir?
The Weapon name (Bayonet, AUG, Galil AR, P250)
The skin name (Contractor, Orange DDPAT, Modern Hunter, Fade)
The wear (Factory New, Battle-Scarred, Field-Tested, Well Worn, Minimal Wear)?
```

How would I go about it?

Comment: [Bob's your uncle](https://regex101.com/r/fM3pK3/1)

Answer (score 0):

For the first three things you can simply use some basic [**regular expressions**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). In this case it's quite simple. For example you can use `/Souvenir/` to match if a string contains the text `"Souvenir"`, and you use [**`preg_match()`**](http://php.net/preg_match) for the test.

```
if (preg_match("/Souvenir/", "Souvenir AUG | Contractor (Factory New)")) 
    echo "It's Souvenir!";
```

You can apply the exact same idea for `/StatTrak™/` and `/★/`.

For the weapon name you simply need to note where that occurs in the string. If we spit the string by `"|"`, the weapon is always the first line of text. Further more if there are two words the weapon is the second word, while if there is a single word the weapon is that word. In general it going to be the last word. Here is an example:

```
$str = "★ StatTrak™ Bayonet | Fade (Minimal Wear)";
$items = explode("|",$str);                           // Split by "|"
$words = array_filter(explode(" ",$items[0]));        // Split first text by space
$weapon = $words[sizeof($words)-1];                   // Get last word in text
echo $weapon;
```

The skin name is similar, in that case it's the second line of text after the `"|"`, but excluding the items inside parentheses. To remove parenthesized text from a string see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336672/php-remove-brackets-contents-from-a-string).

Finally the wear is the second line of text after `"|"` and is the text inside the parentheses. To exact the contents of text inside parentheses see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196520/php-best-way-to-extract-text-within-parenthesis).

Answer (score -1):

You can search about [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) and [`regex`](http://regexr.com/). These are good points to start.

Comment: I've already looked into that, but it's such a headache. I just don't know how it works.